# Best Practice of Types Used In Readers/Writers/Processors?

Tags: java, spring-batch

A colleague and myself are having a debate if the intention of the authors of Spring Batch was to use concrete types in readers/writer/processors, or

The method signatures for spring batch reader / writer / processors are:

```
public interface ItemReader<T>
public interface ItemWriter<T>
public interface ItemProcessor<I, O>
```

Was the intention to primarily use Readers/Writers/Processors in a "strongly typed" manner, such as:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String address;
    String age;
}

public class PersonReader implements ItemReader<Person> { ... }
```

Or was it more intended to handle a bucket full of types, such as:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String address;
    String age;
}

public class Animal {
    String type;
    String color;
}

public class Book {
    String title;
    String pages;
    String author;
}

public class UpdateObject {
    Person person;
    Animal animal;
    Book book;
}

public class UpdateObjectReader implements ItemReader<UpdateObject>  { ... }
```

Comment: *"The method signatures" are `public interface ItemReader<T>`* ... *method* signatures? And to be honest I don't think the author cares about how you use these interfaces. It is up to you and your code style. And since there is no real difference between both cases, since they are just classes with an arbitrary amount of field of an arbitrary type, it doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the conceptual difference between `UpdateObject` (containing `Person`, `Animal` and `Book` fields) and a `Person` (containing `String`, `String` and `String` fields)?

Comment: The first one might be more scalable because the second one is composed by `Person`, `Animal` and `Book`. Not sure you want the process three different classes at the same time, since there're no significant relation among them.